# What This Systolic Blood Pressure Wants to Explain To Us?

Tags: machine-learning

Good day. I know how thin plate spline is used for smoothing splines since I've been using it personally in my research field. I am just totally confused why lattice of knots (red and blue) are used in this figure with a contour plot. What this image really wants to expound to us? Any ideas folks?[image]

Comment: The figure depict samples of systolic blood pressure as a function of age and obesity. The goal is to use these samples to infer a continuous relationship between said variables using [thin plate splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_plate_spline). The color of the knots (meeting points of the splines) indicate the subspace in which we care about the accuracy of the approximation. Welcome to the site.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome Emre. :) Then what is the purpose of the  "black" curved lines dividing these data points?

Comment: Black curved lines are dividing the data points plotted as obesity vs age into buckets of length 5.

Comment: As mentioned in the first sentence, they are [contour lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line), whose values are written at the right end of each contour. The contours are presumably derived from the spline.

Comment: So that means if we are going to average these all approximated "black" curved lines, then we will likely arrive around the bucket 140?

Comment: I am just confused why it needs to plot those contour lines, if you can only show one smooth curve line that interpolates/approximates these data points(which is actually the basic idea in regressions)?

Comment: Yeah, I agree, they are derived by using thin plate spline radial basis functions. But what's the need of showing all those thin plate splines, if, we can show a single thin plate spline that approximates these data set of points?

Comment: Thank you pals for your inputs, I think I have understood it now, at least. :)

Comment: These splines are built such that you are separating the points you have plotted into some buckets of sys. pressure. If you had just wanted two sets say `sys.pressure < 135` and `>= 135`. Then you can have one complex spline that can do the job for you.